# Is the initState method called again, when the App is closed but still running in the background (Flutter)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am curious whether the app would be rebuild, thus, calling initState again, if the user just closes the app, but does not close it in the background. Does it make a difference if the user instantly reopens the app compared to coming back a couple hours later? Or would the app just be frozen in the state it had when it was closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No initState is not call after came back from background..
You can use `WidgetsBindingObserver`  for this type of work..